# how to concatenate variables into a variable with java

Tags: java

I would like to concatenate a few variables into a string variable but I am unable to get it to work. When I compile it says "not a statement" and "; expected."

```
float a = 1;
float b = 2;
String resW;
```

My purpose is to concatenate "a" and "b" and assign it to resW.

```
resW = a " + " b;
```

My ultimate goal is to use resW as such...

```
System.out.println(resW);
bufferedWriter.write(resW);
```

It should save to a file in the format of "1 + 2". I don't understand how to do this properly or if this is even possible.

Comment: You can concatenate with a `+`. Use `resW = a + " + " + b;`

Comment: In addition to @Codebender 's suggestion, if you want to only display whole integers instead of 1.0 + 2.0, cast variables a and b to an int. i.e. `resW = (int)a + " + " + (int)b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String resW = a + " + " + b;
```

try this..

Comment: `a + " + " + b` will do, there's no need for `Integer.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

```
resW = a + " + " + b;
```

Use a plus sign to concatenate Strings.

It should allow an autoconversion from `float` to `String`, but if it doesn't, you can change the `float`s to `Float`s, and do:

```
resW = a.toString() + " + " + b.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `resW`, you could try this:

```
public class QuickTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        float a = 1;
        float b = 2;

        System.out.println(String.format("%.0f + %.0f", a, b));
        System.out.println(String.format("%.2f + %.2f", a, b));
        System.out.println(String.format("%.5f + %.5f", a, b));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1 + 2
1.00 + 2.00
1.00000 + 2.00000
```

**Note:**

- If you insist, you could do something like `String resW = String.format(...);`
- [String#format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) can help you 'beautify' your resulting string, allowing you to specify the number of decimal places, alignment, etc

Comment: Thanks Gosu. That's not what I was looking for but I also have not seen that technique before. I am sure that I can find a use for the different amounts of decimal places in future programs. Awesome tip!