# Printing out the sum of even and odd numbers in a while loop java

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Eigth {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

  int x=0, number1, number2;

  System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
  number1=s.nextInt();

  if(number1 == x) {
     System.out.println("Error");  
     System.exit(0);  
  } 

  System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
  number2=s.nextInt();

  if (number2 == x) {
     System.out.println("Error");
     System.exit(0);
  }

  if(number2 <= number1) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);    
  }

 while (number1 <= number2) {
     if ((number1 % 2) == 0)
        System.out.println("\"" + number1 + " IS EVEN\"");
     else
        System.out.println("\"" + number1 + " IS ODD\"");
        number1++;  
  }    

 int evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0, i = number1;
 while(i <= number2) {
     if(i % 2 == 0) {
     evenSum += i;
  } 
     else {
     oddSum += i;
  }
     i++;
}


System.out.println("Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum);
System.out.println("Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: " + oddSum);
System.out.println("Sum of All Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum + oddSum);

}
}
```

I have to prompt the user for two numbers and the first number entered is what the loop should start at and the second number entered is what the loop should go up to. If the first or second number is 0, I have to print out error. If the second number is not greater than the first, I have to do the same thing. Then, I have to print out the sum of all even, odd, and total sum of the numbers in the loop. However, with the code I have, it prints out as Sum of All even numbers: 0, sum of all odd numbers:0, and sum of all numbers: 0 , no matter what numbers I put in. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different languages.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601786/how-to-concatenate-variables-into-a-variable-with-java

Comment: Do you have to use a while loop? for something running from running to a for loop is well suited

Comment: System.out.println("Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum) ;

Comment: @Aalexander yes it has to be a while loop

Comment: @user9339131 When I do System.out.println("Sum of even Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum); it just prints out as Sum of even Numbers in Loop: 0 which makes sense because I have int evenSum = 0 , I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Michael I tested your code. It gave me correct output. Your logic is also correct. Could you share the full code? There might be some errors there. Also please share the input for which your code is not working.

Comment: @AKSingh I edited the question so it's my full code now. I think I'm messing up somewhere at the top and it's affecting everything else. I'm not sure

Comment: can you show the sample input and expected output please?

Comment: you're taking a range of numbers, right?

Comment: @XO56 I'm sorry I'm completely new to all of this, it's only my second week ever learning anything like this. I'm not sure what you mean by that, I'm so new. But this is the example she gave us: example user enters 5 for amount to loop...
starting at 0
"0 IS EVEN!"
"1 IS ODD!"
"2 IS EVEN!"
"3 IS ODD!"
"4 IS EVEN!"

Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: 6
Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: 4
Sum of All Numbers in Loop: 10

Comment: @XO56 ya I'm just finding the sum of all the even numbers in the loop and then the sum of the odd numbers and then the sum of all of them in the loop

Comment: got it!.... i'm on . just a minute please :)

Comment: @XO56 thank you so much for the help:) I've been stuck on this for days lol

Comment: I've given an answer to your question. Does it solve your problem? However, there is a much more efficient way to solve this problem without loop. wanna try?

Comment: What I think is, you should assign the initial value of `number1 = 0`, it mayhelp

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `int i = 0` to `int i = number 1` as you want to start from the number that is inputted.

Also putting these at the end works

```java
System.out.println("Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum);
System.out.println("Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: " + oddSum);
System.out.println("Sum of All Nuumbers in Loop: " + totalSum);
```

The output depends on the numbers input, if the first number input is smaller than the second number input then it gives the numbers. I tested this with the first number being 2 and the second number being 4 and my output was:

```
Enter a number
2
Enter another number
4
Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: 6
Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: 3
Sum of All Numbers in Loop: 9
```

With another input:

```
Enter a number
8
Enter another number
20
Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: 54
Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: 36
Sum of All Numbers in Loop: 90
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to have a separate variable to keep the total sum as the sum of even and odd would return the total sum. Also, the while loop looks a bit complicated. you could simplify as below:

```java
int evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0;
int i = number1;
while(i <= number2) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        evenSum += i;
    } else {
        oddSum += i;
    }
    i++;
}

System.out.println("Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum);
System.out.println("Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: " + oddSum);
System.out.println("Sum of All Nuumbers in Loop: " + (evenSum + oddSum));
```

Comment: I edited my question and added my full code, and it's not working. I think I messed something else up that's affecting everything at the end but I can't figure it out

Comment: @Michael Why have you used `while (number1 <= number2) {` this loop? Because at the end of the loop, `number1` would be equal to `number2` and the loop to find the sum would never be executed. So the sum variable remain at 0.

Answer (score 0):

After doing your range checks on `number1` and `number2` you can shorten your algorithm a little by using the remainder value as an index into an array to tally the values.

```
int[] sums = new int[2];

while (number1 <= number2) {
    sums[number1 % 2] += number1++;
}

System.out.println("Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: " + sums[0]);
System.out.println("Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: " + sums[1]);
System.out.println("Sum of All Numbers in Loop: " + (sums[0] + sums[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Michael, you have made a simple logical error. The origin of the error is in the first while loop. Here is the *first* `while` loop in your code:

```
while (number1 <= number2)
{
    if ((number1 % 2) == 0)
        System.out.println("\"" + number1 + " IS EVEN\"");
    else
        System.out.println("\"" + number1 + " IS ODD\"");
    
    number1++;  
}
```

The error is that you are constantly updating variable `number1` here. After the *first* `while` loop add this statement:

```
//Debugging 
System.out.println ("number1: " + number1 + "  number2: " + number2);
```

For example: If you inputted `number1` as `2` and `number2` as `6`. Then the above statement *if placed after the **first** `while` loop*, will print the following.

> number1: 7  number2: 6

Since the value of `number1` is always greater than `number2`, and you assign this `updated` value of `number1` to `i`, this part of your code will never execute.

```
 //if number1 = 2 and number2 = 6
 //before the starting of the while loop below, the value of `i` is 7 
 //which is greater than number2 which is 6
 while(i <= number2) 
 {
     if(i % 2 == 0) 
     {
         evenSum += i;
     } 
     else
     {
         oddSum += i;
     }
    
     i++;
 }
```

For your second doubt, you can get the correct answer if you change your statement to this:

```
//This statement is old and causing error
System.out.println ("Sum of All Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum+oddSum);

//This is updated statement that gives correct answer
//Notice the added brackets 
System.out.println ("Sum of All Numbers in Loop: " + (evenSum+oddSum));
```

The reason this happens is because if you do not use extra brackets, `evenSum` and `oddSum` will be considered as `String` (*You said you are a beginner. **If you do not know what `String` is, skip this explanation.** You will be taught later about it and then you will be able to understand it*). which results in `string concatenation`. However, after using the extra brackets, `evenSum` and `oddSum` will be considered as `int` and normal addition is performed which results in total sum.

I also made an extra change and removed variable `x`. *It was not necessary to use it*. The `if` can be changed to this:

```
//Replace x with 0
if (number1 == 0)
{
    System.out.println("Error");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Here is the whole updated code with added comments for better understanding:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //No need of x here
    int number1, number2 , tempNumber1;

    System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
    number1 = scanner.nextInt();

    //Replace x with 0
    if (number1 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
    number2 = scanner.nextInt();

    //Replace x with 0
    if (number2 == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if( number2 <= number1)
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Storing the value of number1 is necessary to preserve its value
    tempNumber1 = number1;

    while (number1 <= number2)
    {
        if ((number1 % 2) == 0) System.out.println("\"" + number1 + " IS EVEN\"");
        else System.out.println("\"" + number1 + " IS ODD\"");

        number1++;
    }

    //Use total, it keeps the logic straight
    //You can also use only oddSum and evenSum and calculate total later
    //See below for more information
    int evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0, i = tempNumber1, total = 0;

    while(i <= number2)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0) evenSum += i;
        else oddSum += i;

        total += i;
        i++;
    }


    System.out.println("Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum);
    System.out.println("Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: " + oddSum);
    //If you do not use total and have only used oddSum and evenSum, use the below commented line
    //System.out.println ("Sum of All Numbers in Loop: " + (evenSum+oddSum));
    System.out.println("Sum of All Numbers in Loop: " + total);
}
```

An advice: If you are not sure what is happening, try using `System.out.println(*what you want to print*)` for `checking the value` of `different variables`. I did this in my answer. If you want to see where, find the statement which has a `//debugging` comment above it .  It will help you to find errors more quickly.

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much this helped me so much. The only issue I am having ow is the last part when I do System.out.println("Sum of All Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum + oddSum). Let's say I put in 2 and 4 for number 1 and number 2, the even sum gives me 6 and the odd sum gives me 3, but the sum of all numbers in loop gives me 63, when it should be 9 I believe

Comment: This is an example of what outputs when I input 2 and 4. Also, how would I get rid of the "5" after the "4 IS EVEN"? 

Enter first number: 2
Enter second number: 4
"2 IS EVEN"
"3 IS ODD"
"4 IS EVEN"
5
Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: 6
Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: 3
Sum of All Numbers in Loop: 63

Comment: @Michael This is happening because of concatenation! while you concat a string with integer it become a string!  For instance, `("abc" + 5 + 6)` --> `("abc5" + 6)` --> `("abc56")`. do some research on java concatenation.

Comment: @Michael I have updated my answer. I made it more simple for better understanding. Do comment if you have any other problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean flag = true;
while(flag){
    int start = sc.nextInt();
    int end = sc.nextInt();
    
    if((end - start) <= 0 || start == 0 || end == 0){
        System.out.println("Error");
    }else{
        int evenSum = 0, oddSum = 0;
        for(int i = start; i <= end; i++){
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                evenSum += i;
            }else{
                oddSum += i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: " + evenSum);
        System.out.println("Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: " + oddSum);
        System.out.println("Sum of All Numbers in Loop: " + (evenSum + oddSum));
        
        flag =false;
    }
}
```

inputs: `1 5`
Output:

```
Sum of Even Numbers in Loop: 6
Sum of Odd Numbers in Loop: 9
Sum of All Numbers in Loop: 15
```

The first `while loop` is to take inputs until the user give `valid inputs`.